# What is the result of buffering a buffered stream in java?

Tags: java, stream, java-io, bufferedinputstream

Was writing the javadoc for :

```
/**
 * ...Buffers the input stream so do not pass in a BufferedInputStream ...
 */
public static void meth(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,
            INPUT_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);
    // rest omitted
}
```

But is it really a problem to pass a buffered input stream in ? So this :

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/file"), SIZE);
meth(is);
```

would buffer the `is` into `bis` - or would java detect that `is` is already buffered and set `bis = is` ? If yes, would different buffer sizes make a difference ? If no, why not ?
NB : I am talking about input streams but actually the question is valid for output streams too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is it really a problem to pass a buffered input stream in ?

Not really.  There is potentially a small overhead in doing this, but it is negligible compared with the overall cost of reading input.

If you look at the code of `BufferedInputStream`, (e.g. the [`read1`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#BufferedInputStream.read1%28byte%5B%5D,int,int%29) method) you will see that block reads are implemented to be efficient when buffered streams are stacked.

> [Re the example code:] would java detect that is is already buffered and set `bis = is` ?

No.

> If no, why not ?

Because Java (the language, the compiler) generally doesn't understand the semantics of Java library classes.  And in this case, since the benefit of such an optimization would be negligible, it i not worthwhile implementing.

Of course, you are free to write your `meth` method to do this kind of thing explicitly ... though I predict that it will make little difference.

---

> I do not quite get why in read1 they "bother" to copy to the input buffer only if the requested length is less than the buf.length (or if there is a marked position in the input stream)

I assume that you are referring to this code (in `read1`):

```
    if (len >= getBufIfOpen().length && markpos < 0) {
        return getInIfOpen().read(b, off, len);
    }
```

The first part is saying that if the user is asking for less than the stream's configured buffer size, we don't want to short-circuit the buffering.  (Otherwise, we'd have the problem that doing a `read(byte[], int, int)` with a small requested length would be pessimal.)

The second part is to do with the way that mark / reset is implemented.  Instead of using mark / reset on the underlying stream (which may or may not be supported), a `BufferedInputStream` uses the buffer to implement it.  What you are seeing is part of that logic.  (You can work the details for yourself ... reading the comments in the source code.)

Comment: while I do not quite get why in `read1` they "bother"  to copy to the input buffer only if the requested length is less than the buf.length (or if there is a marked position in the input stream) your answer gives the most insight so I am accepting it

Answer (score 1):

If you buffer the stream twice then it will use more memory and be slower than if you only did so once, but it will still work.

It's certainly worth documenting that your stream does buffering so that users will know they don't need to do so themselves.

Generally it's best to discourage rather than actively prevent this sort of misuse.

Comment: Check the source code. BufferedInputStream has a 'greased path' for the case where entire bufferloads are being copied, which minimizes the damage if you stack them.

Comment: @EJP Sure; it would be peculiar if it didn't. But the cost is non-zero, so I don't think that alters what I said.

Comment: The cost is non-zero how? One extra method call is nothing compared to the actual I/O.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, Java would not detect the double buffering.

It is up to the user to avoid this problem. The `BufferedInputStream` has no way of knowing whether the `InputStream` you pass into the constructor is buffered or not.

Here is the source code for the `BufferedInputStream` constructor:

```
public BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size) {
    super(in);
    if (size <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    buf = new byte[size];
}
```

**EDIT**

From the comments *is it a problem to double buffer a stream?*

The short answer is **yes**.

The idea of buffering is to increase speed so that data is spooled into memory and written out (usually to very slow IO) in chunks. If you double buffer you spool data into memory and then flush that data *back into memory* somewhere else. This certainly has a cost in terms of speed...

Comment: Why not `is instanceof BufferedInputStream` ? Could you provide a link to the source ?

Comment: But what about `DataInputStream`? `ObjectInputStream`? `MyRandomBufferedStream`? There is simply no way to detect whether a stream is buffered.

Comment: Kind of thought this, but maybe there was some hack - the question remains : is it a problem to double buffer a stream ? Should I add this clause to the java doc ? ;)

Comment: Check the source code. `BufferedInputStream` has a 'greased path' for the case where entire bufferloads are being copied, which minimizes the damage if you stack them.